# Android Sdk integration in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk

what does sdk integration mean in android. I searched much about sdk integration but didn't find a easy answer to understand it well.

Comment: SDK integration is a very open term. A software development kit (SDK or "devkit") is typically a set of software development tools that allows the creation of applications for a certain software package. 
Every SDK has its own way of integration with different applications.

Comment: Which SDK are you talking about? Facebook, Twitter, Aviary??

Answer (score 1):

At first we need to know What is [SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit)?  SDK is a software development kit. There are lots of SDK  like [Google Map SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/?hl=en), [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android), [Twitter SDK](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android) etc. Now if you want to make a android application which would be able to share something in facebook or twitter, then you must need  facebook or twitter SDK for your app . This kind of uses of some other sdk in your app is called Facebook  SDK or Twitter SDK  Integration with android . For other hand if
 you want to make a ios app which would be able to use google map then you need to integrate Google Map SDK with your ios app. This is called SDK integration....That's it. Thank You